# Failed to package application. [ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 6

Tags: android, sencha-touch

I am getting following error while trying to package sencha app in Android simulator.

> Failed to create android project
>
> Failed to package application.
>
> [ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 6

I follow this article step by step:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/android-setup-for-sencha-touch/

My packager.json:

```
{ 
"applicationName":"AndroidDemo", 
"applicationId":"com.demo.AndroidDemo", 
"bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF", 
"versionString":"1.0", 
"versionCode":"1", 
"icon": { 
    "36":"resources/icons/Icon_Android36.png", 
    "48":"resources/icons/Icon_Android48.png", 
    "57":"resources/icons/Icon.png", 
    "72":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png", 
    "114":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png", 
    "144":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png" 
}, 
"inputPath":"./",    
"outputPath":"../build", 
"configuration":"Debug", 
"platform":"AndroidEmulator", 
"deviceType":"Universal", 
"certificatePath":"C:/Users/Rohit/bin/android-sdk-windows/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/android.keystore", 
"certificateAlias":"android1", 
"certificatePassword":"android1", 
"provisionProfile":"", 
"notificationConfiguration":"", 
"sdkPath":"C:/Users/Rohit/bin/android-sdk-windows/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030", 
"androidAPILevel":"19", 
"permissions":[ "INTERNET", "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE", "CAMERA", "VIBRATE", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "CALL_PHONE" ], 
"orientations": [ "portrait", "landscapeLeft", "landscapeRight", "portraitUpsideDown" ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the latest versions of Sencha Touch (2.4) and Sencha Cmd (5.0.x) then you need to use Cordova or PhoneGap - STBuild is no longer supported. That may be the issue.

See this link about [how to integrate PhoneGap and Cordova](http://www.sencha.com/blog/leveraging-phonegap-within-sencha-touch/).

Comment: Thanks for the information and support. I will try.